# How regional is Hinduism?

Tags: culture, bhakti, india, language

I know that different Gods, or different manifestations of Ultimate Reality, are worshiped in different regions. Furthermore, there is a lot of linguistic diversity across Bhārat.

So, I'm wondering:

- Is it difficult to practice a form of Sānātana Dharma that differs from the majority in a particular area?
  For example, there are many temples to Ganesha in Maharashtra. But, I think there are few in Uttar Pradesh. So, is it difficult for Ganesha devotees to practice in Uttar Pradesh?
- If someone is devoted to a particular deity, should they try to live nearer a temple dedicated to that one?
- Is it difficult to discuss philosophy & scriptures in a region which predominantly speaks a different language?
  For example, is it difficult for someone from Kashmir to discuss the Bhagavad Gita with someone in Tamil Nadu?

Comment: again, you are asking different unrelated questions under one heading. edit your question to one question, and some are asking for opinions.

Comment: These are three parts to a single question: how much does region affect Hindu practice. This is already narrowing out other factors like, food, customs, dress. I only want to know how regionality affects practice.

Comment: @RubelliteFae There are some regional differences. For example, the Tamil Veda is very important to the Sri Vaishnava community, and so a non-Tamilian might have problems adopting Sri Vaishnvaism. So some scriptures in one particular language will attract followers in that region. And indeed, most Sri Vaishnavas live in Tamil Nadu and near Sri Vaishnava temples and Divya Desams. The Bhagavad Gita is followed universally across India, so the Kashmiri and Tamilian wont have problems discussing it if they speak a language they both understand.

Comment: "so the Kashmiri and Tamilian wont have problems discussing it if they speak a language they both understand." But, is such a thing common? I know that many people speak English and Hindi, but I don't know how common they are.

Comment: No there is no such problem. One can worship his/her deity anywhere. @Rubellite

Comment: @Ikshvaku Come outside of Tamil and Nadu,  people are not bound with a region. A Vaishnavite can be found outside Tamil and Nadu also. Also I disagree that most Vaishnavite live in Tamil and Nadu only.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I said *Sri* Vaishnavas, not all Vaishnavas

Comment: Oh  Another sub sect out of a sect! !

Comment: 1. Possibly. 2. Would be nice iIf they have the means and the opportunity 3. Philosophical discussions to this day happen in Sanskrit. Scholars sometimes traveled to seats of learning like Kasi and engage in debates/discussions. Sringeri Jagadguru conducts religious/philosophical conference/seminar annually and these happen in Sanskrit.

Comment: I don't know why this is considered too broad, nor why it is on hold. @moonstar already answered my question perfectly, but added it as a comment, so I could not pick it.

Comment: All three of the questions get to the point of, "Should one try to live in an area where their sect is popular?" without asking in a way that can be construed as opinion.

Comment: Q: "Should one try to live in an area where their sect is popular?"  Answer: nowhere there is any such restriction in shashtras nor said by any acharyas.